# Multiply an array (k,) or (k, n) by 1D array (k,)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I sometimes work with 1D arrays:

```
A = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

or 2D arrays (mono or stereo signals read with `scipy.io.wavfile`):

```
A = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7,8]])
```

Without having to distinguish these 2 cases with an `if A.ndim == 2:`..., is there a simple one-line solution to multiply this array `A` by an 1D array `B = np.linspace(0., 1., 4)`?

If `A` is 1D, then it's just `A * B`, and if `A` is 2D, what I mean is multiply each line of `A` by each element of `B`.

---

Note: this question arises naturally when working with both mono and stereo sounds read with `scipy.io.wavfile`.

Comment: By A*B you mean element-wise multiplication, producing a 4-vector?

Comment: @Denziloe yes indeed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Approach #1**

We can use [`einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) to cover generic ndarrays -

```
np.einsum('i...,i->i...',A,B)
```

The trick that works here is the `ellipsis` that broadcasts for the trailing dimensions after the first axis as they are in `A` and keeps them in the output, while keeping the first axes for the two inputs aligned, which is the intended multiplication here. With `A` as `1D` array, there's no broadcasting and that essentially reduces to : `np.einsum('i,i->i',A,B)` under the hoods.

Schematically put :

```
A   :  i x ....
B   :  i 
out :  i x ....
```

Hence, covers for `A` with any number of dimensions.

More info on the use of `ellipsis` from the docs :

> To enable and control broadcasting, use an ellipsis. Default
>   NumPy-style broadcasting is done by adding an ellipsis to the left of
>   each term, like np.einsum('...ii->...i', a). To take the trace along
>   the first and last axes, you can do np.einsum('i...i', a), or to do a
>   matrix-matrix product with the left-most indices instead of rightmost,
>   you can do np.einsum('ij...,jk...->ik...', a, b).

**Approach #2**

Using the fact that we are trying to align the first axis of `A` with the only axis of 1D array `B`, we can simply transpose `A`, multiply with `B` and finally transpose back -

```
(A.T*B).T
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain why does it work/how it works? What should the `i...,i->i...` syntax be? Even if it is short, it looks like the kind of syntax difficult to remember / difficult to understand when re-reading the code 6 months later.

Comment: Not really.  `numpy` is designed to broadcast from the right.  Trying to broadcast from the left is going to require something like `einsum` that allows explicit broadcasting.

Comment: @Basj Added some explanation.